# Seems impossible to disable JavaScript validation in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation, jsdt, eclipse-jsdt

I know that there are many questions on stackoverflow regarding this issue, but none of them solve the issue at all and I need deeper insight into this problem. I have tried everything that everyone suggested and more, to no avail whatsoever.

I have:

- disabled the JavaScript Validation in Preferences -> Validation
- disabled JavaScript semantic validation in Preferences -> JavaScript -> Validator -> Errors/Warnings
- disabled all relevant builders in project properties
- manually edited my .project file to remove all JavaScript-related items
- edited the 'Include path' for JavaScript in Preferences -> JavaScript -> Include Path
- added exclusion patterns to my project JavaScript settings
- manually located the nodejs executable that the Tern plugin used and deleted it just in case that would do anything
- deleted the JSDT plugin altogether
- anything and everything else that I could possibly think of

And yet JavaScript is still validated (improperly, of course, because eclipse's JavaScript validation is terrible). This causes constant hangs and freezes and makes the experience so terrible I'm considering managing the whole project in Notepad++. I cannot understand how this could be so difficult to fix.

Any insight would be profoundly appreciated.

FWIW, it's a maven-based project using a wildfly archetype.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the view **menu** of the ***Project Explorer*** choose ***Customize View...***; then in the dialog **in the *Content* tab** disable ***JavaScript Elements***.

You also have to disable the *Validation* builder (right-click on project folder: *Properties* > *Builders*) and delete the errors in the *Problems* view to get rid of all JS errors.

Comment: I'll look into your response tomorrow morning, thanks.

Comment: the Customize View -> Content -> JavaScript Elements thing seems to have finally worked. Thanks.